# how to change odd and even overflow menu items background

Tags: android, menuitem

How to change odd and even overflow menu items background in android?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        if (i%2==0){
            //If it is even
            menu.getItem(i).getActionView().setBackground();
        }else{
            //If it is odd
            menu.getItem(i).getActionView().setBackground();
        }
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Whether your menu is useful `actionViewClass`?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this way in your `custom adapter getView()` method:-

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A4A4A4"));
} else {
rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBF00"));
}
```

I hope this will help you, if not then please tell me.